# why file attachment in oneNote(Mac) is locked and how to bypass it?

Tags: mac, onenote

I want to edit file attachment like pdf and txt file in oneNote directly and save all the changes, but all the file attached in the oneNote when opened is automatically locked, I uncheck the lock option but the change not save into the file

How can I solve this irritating issue

Comment: When I try and change a textedit document it gives me the option to unlock the document so I can save it. What application(s) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible right now, because files attached to OneNote-notes are always read-only copies in the current version. If you edit them, Mac OS X saves the changes to a copy of the file in a location you can choose. To update the online copy of your file with your changes, you'd have to remove the old version of the file from the note and attach the copy with your new changes to it.